# Possibilities to use iphone memory

Tags: ios4, memory-management

I am implementing a web service based application. In that I need to download 500mb sized audio files and I need to store them into local database. As I know that one application can use 30 mb only. But as my requirement I need to support 500 mb. Is this possible? Is there any way to use iphone real memory for our application?

Thank you,S

Comment: I don't think there is a 30mb limit. Where did you learn about this?

I mean, all the navigation apps have app sizes close to 1 gigabyte.